# How to display attributes of belongsTo object in Ember.js template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, relationships

In my Ember app, a survey belongsTo a user; a user hasMany surveys. In my template, I would like to display a list of surveys, and the name of the user that created them. For now, I am pushing side-loaded data into the store via the application route, and it is showing up in the ember inspector->Data. The survey info is displaying correctly in the template, but the corresponding user's firstName will not appear. Help/guidance appreciated.

**survey.js** (model)

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true}), //tried without async as well
  title: DS.attr(),
  post: DS.attr()
});
```

**user.js** (model)

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  surveys: DS.hasMany('survey', {async: true}),  
  firstName: DS.attr()
});
```

**application.js** (application route)

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    this.store.push({
      data: [{
        id: 1,
        type: 'survey',
        attributes: {
          title: 'My First Survey',
          post: 'This is my Survey!'
        },
        relationships: {
          user: 1
        }
      }, {
        id: 2,
        type: 'survey',
        attributes: {
          title: 'My Second Survey',
          post: 'This is survey 2!'
        },
        relationships: {
          user: 1
        }
      }, {
        id: 1,
        type: 'user',
        attributes: {
          firstName: 'Tyler'
        },
        relationships: {
          surveys: [1, 2]
        }
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

**surveys.js** (route)

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model () {
    return this.store.findAll('survey');
  }
});
```

**surveys.hbs** (template)

```
<ul>
  {{#each model as |survey|}}
    <li>
      <strong>{{survey.title}}</strong> //This works
      <br>
      {{survey.post}}                   //This works
      <br>
      Author: {{survey.user.firstName}} //This does not work
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

**SOLUTION** - updated application.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    this.store.push({
      "data": [      //Added double quotes throughout to conform to documentation
        {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "survey",
          "attributes": {
            "title": "My First Survey",
            "post": "This is my Survey!"
          },
          "relationships": {
            "user": {
              "data": {
                "id": "1",
                "type": "user"
              }
            }
          }
        }, {
          "id": "2",
          "type": "survey",
          "attributes": {
            "title": "My Second Survey",
            "post": "This is survey 2!"
          },
          "relationships": {
            "user": {
              "data": {
                "id": "1",
                "type": "user"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "included": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "user",
          "attributes": {
            "firstName": "Tyler"
          } //no need to include user's relationships here
        }
      ]
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you try `{{log}}`ing or outputting `{{survey.user}}` to see what's there? Also, I doubt if it makes any difference, but try using unique IDs across models. BTW, async should not make any difference in this case.

Comment: No luck with unique IDs. Thought the same on async. {{log survey.user}} gives: Class {__ember1442901526467: null, __nextSuper: undefined, __ember_meta__: Object}, looks like it's empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Payload relationship part is not correct. Should be:

```
    relationships: {
      user: {
        data: {
          id: 1,
          type: 'user'
        }
      }
    }
```

Also I think "user" payload should be in "included" section.
[JSONAPISerializer api](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html)

Comment: Thanks a ton--functioning as intended now with changes only to the JSON. May be worth noting that the user's relationships (the hasMany side) do not need to be included. Updated the post with the full solution.